# Partitions of k parts with minimum and maximum part values

Tags: python, algorithm, number-theory

How do I generate the partitions of a number that have exactly k parts, where each part has a minimum and maximum value?

For example, If I want to select all partitions of 21 with 6 parts with minimum part value 3 and the maximum part value is 6, I should get the following partitions:

```
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6]     
[3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5]
[3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

I have the following ascending partition code, courtesy of http://jeromekelleher.net/generating-integer-partitions.html

```
def accel_asc(n):
    a = [0 for i in range(n + 1)]
    k = 1
    y = n - 1
    while k != 0:
        x = a[k - 1] + 1
        k -= 1
        while 2 * x <= y:
            a[k] = x
            y -= x
            k += 1
        l = k + 1
        while x <= y:
            a[k] = x
            a[l] = y
            yield a[:k + 2]
            x += 1
            y -= 1
        a[k] = x + y
        y = x + y - 1
        yield a[:k + 1]
```

and a simple fuction I wrote to only get the partitions I want from the function above:

```
def eligible_partitions(list_of_partitions, min_value, max_value, k):
     l = []
     for x in list_of_partitions:
          if min(x) >= min_value and max(x) <= max_value and len(x) == k:
               l.append(x)
     return l
```

Instead of having to generate and loop through all of the partitions of a particular value, I only want to generate those that meet the specified criteria.

Comment: Why are you trying to generate all fixed-size partitions with given bounds? Are you trying to speed up the computation? Increase memory efficiency? Something else?... The easiest approach would be to change the generating code you have to only yield when the partition matches your criteria, but that might not meet your needs.

Comment: I am trying to speed up the computation. Changing the generating code to yield only partitions that match the criteria is how I want to do that. What I'm struggling with is how to modify the accel_asc function to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
def part(x, n, minval, maxval):
  if not n * minval <= x <= n * maxval:
    return
  elif n == 0:
    yield []
  else:
    for val in range(minval, maxval + 1):
      for p in part(x - val, n - 1, val, maxval):
        yield [val] + p

for p in part(21, 6, 3, 6):
  print p
```

This produces:

```
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5]
[3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it a lot.